# How do I get Pycharm to find a file that I want to use in my code?

Tags: python, macos, ide, pycharm

How do I get Pycharm to find the .txt file that I want to open?

I'm trying to open a file with a simple piece of code

```
file_name = "coding_dna.txt"
my_file = open(file_name)
my_file_contents = my_file.read()

print(my_file_contents)
```

But I keep getting the error below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/NicolasSaenz/Bioinformatics/Pybio.py", line 236, in <module>
    my_file = open(file_name)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'coding_dna.txt'
```

I have tried adding a **init**.py file to the folder containing the file, and I have changed the parent folder to a source root folder through the interpreter.

[folder and subfolders containing file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTtWT.png)

I'm sure that I might just be messing up on something simple, but I can't figure out how to get it to work. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: print current working directory to see where python is executing. `import os` and `print(os.getcwd())`. That will tell you where you could put the file, or you give the full file path like `/home/me/file` or `C:/Users/me/file`

Comment: That worked thanks for the help you guys!

Answer (score 3):

It's possible to set working directory for your program in run configuration.

Just go to `Run - Edit Configurations - Your script configuration` and update 'Working directory' field. See screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By importing the `os` module, we can find where any file is located as long as we have the correct path.

**Try this code below.**

```
import os

path = "C:/Users/NicolasSaenz/(The directory where "coding_dna.txt" is in)"

file_name = os.path.join(path, "coding_dna.txt")
my_file = open(file_name)
my_file_contents = my_file.read()

print(my_file_contents)
```

When printed in my test script, I got the output you're looking for.

Hope this helped!

Comment: You might want to check if this helped!